# c++ undefined symbol when compiling

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, makefile, undefined-symbol

**FIXED: had the method twice in the header file**

I get the following error when trying to compile my project

```
% make
g++ -o p4 testTree.o tree.o node.o check.o
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
Tree::inTree(int)                   tree.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to p4
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `p4'
```

**Makefile**

```
p4: testTree.o tree.o node.o check.o
    g++ -o p4 testTree.o tree.o node.o check.o
testTree.o: testTree.cc tree.h node.h check.h
    g++ -c -Wall -Werror testTree.cc

tree.o: tree.h tree.cc node.h check.h
    g++ -c -Wall -Werror tree.cc
node.o: node.h node.cc check.h
    g++ -c -Wall -Werror node.cc
check.o: check.h check.cc
    g++ -c -Wall -Werror check.cc
clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o p4
```

Relevant code from tree.cc and tree.h:

**tree.cc**

```
...
bool Tree::inTree(int k) const
{
     return locate(k,root) != NULL;
}
...
```

**tree.h**

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include "node.h"
#include "check.h"
using namespace std;
class Tree
{
  private:
    Node *root;
  public:
    Tree();
    Tree(const Tree & t);
    const Tree & operator=(const Tree &t);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const Tree &t);
    bool inTree(int k) const;
    double & operator[](int k);
    double & operator[](int k) const;
    ~Tree();
    bool inTree(int index);
  private:
    Node * locate(int k, Node *rt) const;
    ostream & display(ostream &out, Node *r, int dir=Node::L) const;
    void add(int k, Node*&r);
    void kill(Node *&rt);
    void copy(Node *rt, Node *&newRt);
};
#endif
```

I get the feeling that it's something really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Why is inTree declaraed twice in the .h file? :v
(One const and one non-const)

Comment: Oh derp. lemme fix that

Comment: Yup, that was the error. Thanks a bunch. That's what I get for copying function declarations from one file to another...

Comment: Happens all the time, except in my case, it's usually entire classes :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The message you are getting actually comes from the **linker**, not from the compiler.

One of your member functions, `bool Tree::inTree(int index);`, is correctly declared and defined as a `const` member function:

```
 // Declaration in tree.h
 bool inTree(int index) const;

 // Definition in tree.cc
 bool Tree::inTree(int k) const
 //                       ^^^^^
```

However, in `tree.h` you also define this non-`const` overload of `inTree()`:

```
// Declaration in tree.h, definition (supposedly) nowhere
bool Tree::inTree(int k)
```

For which **no definition is provided**. This is what the linker complains about.

Comment: I had it declared twice, once with (int k), once with (int index). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dazedy: The problem is **not** that you declared it twice with different argument names. Argument names are irrelevant. The problem is that in one case you used the `const` qualifier, and in the other you didn't.

Comment: huh. so without that const, would it just overload depending on the variable name, rather than just the number/type of parameters?

Comment: @Dazedy: No, you would have two declarations of the exact same member function - and the compiler would reject it. Parameter names are irrelevant, only parameter *types* determine a function's signature.

Answer (score 7):

Here is your error:

```
bool Tree::inTree(int k) const
{
 return locate(k,root) != NULL;
}
```

in your `.h` you define

```
bool inTree(int);
```

This is a difference!